# How to automatically deploy the dependencies of a VTK Windows application

Tags: python, windows, deployment, vtk

I am trying to find a tool that can automatically find the dependencies of a VTK Windows application and copies them into the executable folder. Something like the following:

```
windeployvtk.exe myvtkwinapp.exe
```

Is there such a tool available? Would Python be able to do that?

Comment: you can use vcpkg. Some projects even provide the correct list. It has nothing to do with VTK though.